# Error inflating class fragment,I can not solve the error

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, layout-inflater

The map don´t show and don´t know why. I can not figure out what is wrong in the code, if the problem is in the xml or in java ... ie an extra in my application, all of it is running smoothly, but when I click the button to go to MapActivity explodes

**Manifest.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mobimapa"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <permission
          android:name="com.mobimapa.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
          android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="com.mobimapa.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="com.mobimapa.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>


    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>


    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"        
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.mobimapa.AndroidPHPConnectionDemo"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <activity
            android:name="com.mobimapa.MapActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
         <activity
            android:name="com.mobimapa.GetProcessosUser"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.mobimapa.GetProcessosDono"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
         <activity
            android:name="com.mobimapa.UserPage"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.mobimapa.Anotacao"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.mobimapa.GetProcesso"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ProximityActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="com.mobimapa.activity.proximity"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".NotificationView"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter >
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="AIzaSyDb8wLvH5QSeBCUS-dmd-snzMYhHeA5lUQ"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**MapActivity.java**

```
    public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    GoogleMap googleMap;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map);

        // Getting Google Play availability status
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

        // Showing status
        if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ // Google Play Services are not available

            int requestCode = 10;
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
            dialog.show();

        }else { // Google Play Services are available

            // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment of activity_main.xml
            SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

            // Getting GoogleMap object from the fragment
            googleMap = fm.getMap();

            // Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            // Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
            locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // Opening the sharedPreferences object
            sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("location", 0);

            // Getting stored latitude if exists else return 0
            String lat = sharedPreferences.getString("lat", "0");

            // Getting stored longitude if exists else return 0
            String lng = sharedPreferences.getString("lng", "0");

            // Getting stored zoom level if exists else return 0
            String zoom = sharedPreferences.getString("zoom", "0");

            // If coordinates are stored earlier
            if(!lat.equals("0")){

                // Drawing circle on the map
                drawCircle(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(lat), Double.parseDouble(lng)));

                // Drawing marker on the map
                drawMarker(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(lat), Double.parseDouble(lng)));

                // Moving CameraPosition to previously clicked position
                googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(lat), Double.parseDouble(lng))));

                // Setting the zoom level in the map
                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(Float.parseFloat(zoom)));

            }

            googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {

                    // Removes the existing marker from the Google Map
                    googleMap.clear();

                    // Drawing marker on the map
                    drawMarker(point);

                    // Drawing circle on the map
                    drawCircle(point);

                    // This intent will call the activity ProximityActivity
                    Intent proximityIntent = new Intent("com.mobimapa.activity.proximity");

                    // Creating a pending intent which will be invoked by LocationManager when the specified region is
                    // entered or exited
                    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 0, proximityIntent,Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                    // Setting proximity alert
                    // The pending intent will be invoked when the device enters or exits the region 20 meters
                    // away from the marked point
                    // The -1 indicates that, the monitor will not be expired
                    locationManager.addProximityAlert(point.latitude, point.longitude, 20, -1, pendingIntent);

                    /** Opening the editor object to write data to sharedPreferences */
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

                    /** Storing the latitude of the current location to the shared preferences */
                    editor.putString("lat", Double.toString(point.latitude));

                    /** Storing the longitude of the current location to the shared preferences */
                    editor.putString("lng", Double.toString(point.longitude));

                    /** Storing the zoom level to the shared preferences */
                    editor.putString("zoom", Float.toString(googleMap.getCameraPosition().zoom));

                    /** Saving the values stored in the shared preferences */
                    editor.commit();

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Proximity Alert is added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });

            googleMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new OnMapLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
                    Intent proximityIntent = new Intent("com.mobimapa.activity.proximity");

                    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 0, proximityIntent,Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                    // Removing the proximity alert
                    locationManager.removeProximityAlert(pendingIntent);

                    // Removing the marker and circle from the Google Map
                    googleMap.clear();

                    // Opening the editor object to delete data from sharedPreferences
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

                    // Clearing the editor
                    editor.clear();

                    // Committing the changes
                    editor.commit();

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Proximity Alert is removed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void drawMarker(LatLng point){
        // Creating an instance of MarkerOptions
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

        // Setting latitude and longitude for the marker
        markerOptions.position(point);

        // Adding marker on the Google Map
        googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    }

    private void drawCircle(LatLng point){

        // Instantiating CircleOptions to draw a circle around the marker
        CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions();

        // Specifying the center of the circle
        circleOptions.center(point);

        // Radius of the circle
        circleOptions.radius(20);

        // Border color of the circle
        circleOptions.strokeColor(Color.BLACK);

        // Fill color of the circle
        circleOptions.fillColor(0x30ff0000);

        // Border width of the circle
        circleOptions.strokeWidth(2);

        // Adding the circle to the GoogleMap
        googleMap.addCircle(circleOptions);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**map.xml**

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     tools:context=".MapActivity">

    <fragment
        class="com.mobimapa.MapActivity"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Logcat**

> 08-28 03:08:51.950: E/AndroidRuntime(5592): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mobimapa/com.mobimapa.MapActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have  `SupportMapFragment`

```
 <fragment 
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Make sure you have the right imports.

```
 import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;  
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
```

Comment: Thanks, but now i have another GooglePlayServicesUtil(824): Google Play Store is missing ...

Comment: @JPatacas you need a device that has support for google play services. test it on a real device

Comment: @JPatacas map is part of google play services. so check before you use maps http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html. check the topic **Check for Google Play Services**